JPA OneToMany relationship with composite key
I'm trying to setup a OneToMany relation in a Spring project (using Kotlin) using a composite key.
Here is my actual code:
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
data class ItemEntity(
  // ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.itemId", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
  val enchantments: List<ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity> = emptyList(),

  // ...
) {

  // Required by Hibernate to instantiate using reflection
  private constructor() : this(
    // ...
  )
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "item_enchantment_effects")
data class ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity(
  @EmbeddedId
  val id: ItemEnchantmentEffectId,

  @Column(name = "level", nullable = false)
  val level: Int
) {

  // Required by JPA to instantiate using reflection
  private constructor() : this(
    id = ItemEnchantmentEffectId(0L, ItemEnchantmentType.UNBREAKING),
    level = 0
  )
}


@Embeddable
data class ItemEnchantmentEffectId(
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val itemId: Long? = null,

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  val type: ItemEnchantmentType
) : Serializable {
  // Required by JPA to instantiate using reflection
  private constructor() : this(
    type = ItemEnchantmentType.UNBREAKING
  )
}

Thanks to this code, I actually have two tables, and the ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity related table has a composite key, because an item cannot has the same enchant two times.
The issue I am facing is that the item_id is not being updated. In the database, when I save my ItemEntity, the item_id remains equal to 0 (instead of 1, 2, etc.).
In another post, I saw that it was recommended to map the relationship in the opposite direction (ManyToOne) with the type.
Something like:
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("itemId")
val itemEntity: ItemEntity? = null

This solution does not work for me at all because I need an unidirectional relationship. I need to map my entity to a business object and vice versa.
Can someone give me an advice please ?

What are you after exactly? How are you, when creating an ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity instance, going to expect to have the ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity.id.itemId value set?
If you are going to map it with a basic mapping that you aren't updating - you should expect it to always be 0. If you want JPA to manage the value, you have to tell it how - which is why the direction of the relationship matters. Children with FKs to their parents know their parents, parents don't have to know their children. This is really only an issue because you put it in your child composite ID.

Firstly, this statement is a bit contradictory. You say unidirectional, but you're describing a bidirectional relationship.

This solution does not work for me at all because I need an
unidirectional relationship. I need to map my entity to a business
object and vice versa.

I'm assuming, you want to have a bi-directional relation and to be honest, I had reached this particular scenario for one of my side projects, but it was written using java. Regardless of the language, you can easily convert the implementation to kotlin.
The way you solve it is, create a @ManyToOne in the ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity, which internally maps to the itemId from the embedded composite key along with the @OneToMany mapping in ItemEntity.
ItemEntity.java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class ItemEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity> enchantments = new ArrayList<>();
}

ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity.java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_enchantment_effects")
public class ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EnchantmentEffectId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId")
    @MapsId("itemId")
    private ItemEntity item;

    @Column(name = "level", nullable = false)
    private int level;
}

EnchantmentEffectId.java
@Data
@Embeddable
public class EnchantmentEffectId {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    Long itemId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String type;
}


And that's it. Now, you can go ahead and create the repositories and test out your implementation.
Testing:
// ItemEntityRepository.java
@Repository
public interface ItemEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemEntity, Long> {
}


// ItemEnchantmentEffectEntityRepository.java
@Repository
public interface ItemEnchantmentEffectEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity, EnchantmentEffectId> {
}


// ItemController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/items")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemController {

    private final ItemEntityRepository itemEntityRepository;
    private final ItemEnchantmentEffectEntityRepository itemEnchantmentEffectEntityRepository;

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping()
    public void createItems() {
        ItemEntity itemEntity = new ItemEntity();
        itemEntity = itemEntityRepository.save(itemEntity);

        EnchantmentEffectId id = new EnchantmentEffectId();
        id.setItemId(itemEntity.getId());
        id.setType("magical");

        ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity itemEnchantmentEffectEntity = new ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity();
        itemEnchantmentEffectEntity.setId(id);
        itemEnchantmentEffectEntity.setLevel(1);
        itemEnchantmentEffectEntity.setItem(itemEntity);

        itemEnchantmentEffectEntity = itemEnchantmentEffectEntityRepository.save(itemEnchantmentEffectEntity);
        itemEntity.setEnchantments(List.of(itemEnchantmentEffectEntity));
    }
}



Well, this is the solution I'd like to avoid in order to simplify the mapping between my entity and my business class.
Without using a composite key, Hibernate can set the value of item_id on its own. I don’t understand why it can't to do so this time, especially since the mapping is correctly defined in the ItemEntity class.

(Sorry, I can't edit anymore)
By the way, when I wrote unidirectional relationship, I meant that my ItemEntity can retrieve all of his enchantment effects, but I don't need an EnchantmentEffect to retrieve his linked item. So I don't need the ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity to have an item property.

Understood, but id.itemId refers to a field inside the composite key (@EmbeddedId), and JPA does not allow such nested paths in the mappedBy attribute for a embedded key. So, it needs the exact mapping to item in the ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity. Hence the need for @manyToOne mapping. Firstly, I'm suprised, its not thrown an error yet with the nested attribute path in the mappedBy.

Oh well okay... Thank you for your answer !

This is the right answer. If you don't want to map the ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity->ItemEntity , mark it as lazy and never touch it except when creating a new ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity instance. Don't forget to add orphan removal, as you'll want ItemEnchantmentEffectEntity instances deleted when they are dereferenced from ItemEntity enchantments  collections.
